# Fail to Deploy Forge by using Azure

Tags: autodesk-forge

I want to ask about the Deployment of Forge API by Azure.

I had done it through the resource from Learn Forge, and it seems to work smoothly on the local site, but when I try to publish it, Although it shows permission

[image: 1]

after I sign in, it shows 400 error refused, how can I do this for this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is typically caused by an incorrect callback URL for the 3-legged authentication workflow.

When you develop your application locally, you typically set the callback URL (both in your application's code and in https://forge.autodesk.com/myapps) to something like `http://localhost:3000/api/forge/callback/oauth`).

However, when you deploy your application to Azure, AWS, Heroku, or any other cloud hosting provider, the callback URL must be updated accordingly. For example, if you deploy your application as an Azure Web App, the callback URL could look something like `https://my-cool-app.azurewebsites.net/api/forge/callback/oauth`. And again, you'll have to change the URL both in https://forge.autodesk.com/myapps, and in your Azure Web App settings.

Comment: thanks for your advice! It seems that I have changed the URL in Web.config, Azure Web, and Forge app that you mention (https://forge.autodesk.com/myapps), but it shows the same result to me. Is there anything I can do about this situation?

Comment: And are you sure that the settings from _Web.config_ file is really read by your application? Before you initiate the 3-legged workflow, try taking the callback URL that your server is about to use, output it somewhere in the logs, and make sure that it really is the same one.

Comment: Thanks for your advice I will try it step by step.

Comment: Dear, Petr Broz, I deployed successfully through the steps you had given.  I really appreciate it!!

Comment: Good job! And happy to help :)